# How would one estimate the age of a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, estimation, hawking-radiation

The age of the universe is a question that has long been asked and supposedly been answered.

My question however is a lot more specific rather than a general age of the entire universe. How would one estimate the age of an object that is without information? As for instance, any object that falls past the event horizon would have lost all information about itself indefinitely and according to our known laws of physics there is no way to retrieve this information.

I would suppose that there is a method of "guesstimating" the age by looking at what is around the black hole and if the black hole was caused by a supernova, then I'd assume we would look at nova remnants.

But in a scenario, where of course you do not have any nearby objects to look at, and all information about any objects that entered the black hole is lost, then how does one estimate the age of the black hole?

Unless of course such a question is useless to ask anyway and is nonsensical at best (i.e.: "what is north of the north pole?").

Answer (score 4):

It can't be done. As you write, black holes are without information (more commonly people say black holes have "no hair"). Therefore you can't directly estimate the age of a black hole.

What can be done (and it's not always possible) is to use auxiliary information to guess at the age of the black hole. For example, if we find a neutron star and a stellar mass black hole orbiting each other, then we can guess that the two were previously massive stars that went supernova. The age of the black hole is then approximately the age of the neutron star. Similarly, if we observe something orbiting the black hole in a circle, then because this is unlikely (Newton's laws predict an elliptical orbit), we can infer that the system has been around for a long time (because there are processes that drive elliptical orbits to circular, but they take a long time).

Comment: The timescale for an orbit to circularize do not have to be particularly long ( astronomically speaking), depending on the environment. Moreover, there are mechanisms available for the binary to form in a circular orbit to begin with.

Comment: @mmeent those effects/mechanisms are beyond my expertise unfortunately. If you know them well, you might want to write an answer (or edit this one).

Comment: Another example of using auxiliary information is the case of a supermassive galactic black hole producing an [astrophysical jet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophysical_jet). If the length of the jet can be estimated, then that length can be used to put a lower bound on the age of the black hole that produced it.